# Adding headings to data in ListView

Tags: android

I have a ListView that i am populating data from database through SimpleCursorAdapter.The data is to be shown in ListView as

```
Name : Name from database
Class : Class from Database
Marks : Marks from Database
```

I have created a layout with 3 TextViews and correspondingly mapped my table fields to the TextViews

The data from curor takes position in the TextView but the heading as Name: does not appear. How to add these heading to data from database.

thanks
tejinder

Comment: Provide more code so we can take a look at what you're doing.

Comment: kindly let me know what code you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating 3 textview create 6 text view.

text view 1 name fixed string value
text view 2 name from db
text view 3 class
text view 4 class from db and so on.

map only 2,4,6 with data from ur db

Answer (score 0):

You should add your headers before setting the adapter of your ListView, [check this sample](http://elsoufy.blogspot.fr/2013/02/adding-headers-button-to-listview.html).